# How to publish logs in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to use Jenkins to run a script on Linux. The script will run on a Linux slave, generate some log files in Jenkins working directory and tar file in a dedicated place on the slave build server.

Is there a way to publish these log files and tar file to the build result, so they can be inspected/downloaded from the build result page.

Answer (score 5):

Use the "Archive the artfacts" option in the post-build steps of your Jenkins job configuration and specify the paths to the files you want to save.  They will then be linked on the build page under "Last successful artifacts".

Comment: I got this error:ERROR: Failed to archive artifacts: **/*.log
hudson.util.IOException2: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Failed to load jnr.ffi.mapper.FunctionMapper. This is Jenkins ver. 1.509.4 on Linux.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:466)
 at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.loadClassFile(RemoteClassLoader.java:301)
 ... 23 more

Comment: Looks like the comment might be formatting your glob expression incorrectly - are you actually specifying "\*\*/\*.log" ?  If so I'll see if I can figure out the error you're getting.

Comment: Yes, I want to publish the *.log files created under the Jenkins's current workspace directory. Don't know how to configure that.

Comment: Nothing jumps out here - what version of Java are you using to run Jenkins ?

Comment: [root@cmtoldsvnapp01 2013-11-21_11-07-21]# java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: This is a good approach. My logs are at the root of my Workspace. It works also with master/slave Jenkins. I did just enter "*.log" as pattern and checked "Do not fail if archiving returns nothing" in the advanced options.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me - as @gareth_bowles said, my main build page listed them as "Last Successful Artifacts", but they're also shown under "Build Artifacts" within each individual build.

Answer (score 0):

"Archive the artfacts" is one option, or you could copy the logs to %JenkinsDir%\%BUILD_ID%\archive folder as a post build action. Then you can see them as  build artifacts.

Comment: /archive folder is not created without a "Archive the artfacts" option. cp: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/FWST1.0.0/builds/2013-11-21_11-16-34/archive not found

Comment: can you add a build step doing Mkdir Archive before you try to move the logs ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need [Log Parser plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/log-parser) for extracting info from log